# Raspberry Pi as Intermediary USB device

Tags: usb

I have a small project going where I am trying to capture signals from the raspberry pi usb input, record the signal captured via software, and output the signal to my pc after recording via another usb (host to host data-transfer cable).

In other words:

1. I have a usb input device.
2. I have software which can capture/record the signals given to the pi from the usb input device.

*** I need to output the signal(s) to my pc via host-to-host data-transfer usb cable?
I basically want the pi to act as an intermediary which captures/records signals as they are transferred from the input device to my pc.

Is this possible?

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Where should I start given that I have the input device/pi/data-transfer cable?

If it’s not possible, is there any other sort of inexpensive device which can take an usb input / record the input signals / and output the signal to a pc device, acting as an intermediary as described above?

Comment: So called `man-in-the-middle-attack` :) You need to look down the spying and hacking corners of the interweb. I have seen keyboard loggers- I bet that will give you some insight. But that expects a Keyboard device and can store the keys... but you want to store the raw bytes of data, correct?

Comment: I agree with @ppumkin, try something like the Teensy 3.0 which can be programmed to act as a USB HID device. It would be a lot easier to look into transferring your data via the network, wired or wirelessly.